# XML display multiple occurences of nested element

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having soooo much trouble with this. I am trying to create a document which displays seating information for 4 different flights (I'm using a table)... with the way I have it, is only displaying the first instance of the seating information (I only have the "row" element in the XSL for now, until I can figure out how to get it to behave!!!), not going through and displaying all of them. Here's part of the XML (I'm not posting the whole thing because it's very large):

```
 <flights xmlns:BOS="www.boston.com" xmlns:SFO="www.sanfrancisco.com" xmlns:CHI="www.chicago.com" xmlns:HAW="www.hawaii.com" xmlns:LAX="www.losangeles.com">
 <BOS>               
    <orig>BOS</orig>
    <dest>SFO</dest>
    <etd>12pm</etd>
    <eta>3:30pm</eta>
    <num>1185</num>


    <crft>
        Boeing 757
    </crft>

    <crew>
        <pilot>
            <pltfname>James</pltfname>
            <pltlname>Kirk</pltlname>
        </pilot>
        <copilot>
            <copltfname>Mister</copltfname>
            <copltlname>Spock</copltlname>
        </copilot>
    </crew>

    <seating>
        <frstcls cls="Business First" >           <!-- BOS to SFO 1st Class -->  
            <seat>
                <pas>
                    <fname>Unoccupied</fname>
                    <lname>Unoccupied</lname>
                    <age></age>
                </pas>
                <stnum>
                    <row>1</row>
                    <aisle>A</aisle>
                </stnum>
            </seat>
            <seat>
                <pas>
                    <fname>Unoccupied</fname>
                    <lname>Unoccupied</lname>
                    <age></age>
                </pas>
                <stnum>
                    <row>1</row>
                    <aisle>B</aisle>
                </stnum>
            </seat>
            <seat>
                <pas>
                    <fname>Janice</fname>
                    <lname>Rand</lname>
                    <age>adult</age>
           </pas>
                <stnum>
                    <row>1</row>
                    <aisle>E</aisle>
                </stnum>
            </seat>
            <seat>
                <pas>
                    <fname>Unoccupied</fname>
                    <lname>Unoccupied</lname>
                    <age></age>
                </pas>
                <stnum>
                    <row>1</row>
                    <aisle>F</aisle>
                </stnum>
            </seat>

            <seat>
                <pas>
                    <fname>Unoccupied</fname>
                    <lname>Unoccupied</lname>
                    <age></age>
                </pas>
                <stnum>
                    <row>2</row>
                    <aisle>A</aisle>
                </stnum>
            </seat>
            <seat>
                <pas>
                    <fname>Unoccupied</fname>
                    <lname>Unoccupied</lname>
                    <age></age>
                </pas>
                <stnum>
                    <row>2</row>
                    <aisle>B</aisle>
                </stnum>
            </seat>
            <seat>
                <pas>
                    <fname>Unoccupied</fname>
                    <lname>Unoccupied</lname>
                    <age></age>
                </pas>
                <stnum>
                    <row>2</row>
                    <aisle>E</aisle>
                </stnum>
            </seat>
            <seat>
                <pas>
                    <fname>William</fname>
                    <lname>McCoy</lname>
                    <age>adult</age>
                </pas>
                <stnum>
                    <row>2</row>
                    <aisle>F</aisle>
                </stnum>
            </seat>

            <seat>
                <pas>
                    <fname>Unoccupied</fname>
                    <lname>Unoccupied</lname>
                    <age></age>
                </pas>
                <stnum>
                    <row>3</row>
                    <aisle>A</aisle>
                </stnum>
            </seat>
            <seat>
                <pas>
                    <fname>Montgomery </fname>
                    <lname>Scott</lname>
                    <age>adult</age>
                </pas>
                <stnum>
                    <row>3</row>
                    <aisle>B</aisle>
                </stnum>
            </seat>
            <seat>
                <pas>
                    <fname>Unoccupied</fname>
                    <lname>Unoccupied</lname>
                    <age></age>
                </pas>
                <stnum>
                    <row>3</row>
                    <aisle>E</aisle>
                </stnum>
            </seat>
            <seat>
                <pas>
                    <fname>Diane</fname>
                    <lname>Chapel</lname>
                    <age>adult</age>
                </pas>
                <stnum>
                    <row>3</row>
                    <aisle>F</aisle>
                </stnum>
            </seat>

            <seat>
                <pas>
                    <fname>Unoccupied</fname>
                    <lname>Unoccupied</lname>
                    <age></age>
                </pas>
                <stnum>
                    <row>4</row>
                    <aisle>A</aisle>
                </stnum>
            </seat>
            <seat>
                <pas>
                    <fname>Unoccupied</fname>
                    <lname>Unoccupied</lname>
                    <age></age>
                </pas>
                <stnum>
                    <row>4</row>
                    <aisle>B</aisle>
                </stnum>
            </seat>
            <seat>
                <pas>
                    <fname>Unoccupied</fname>
                    <lname>Unoccupied</lname>
                    <age></age>
                </pas>
                <stnum>
                    <row>4</row>
                    <aisle>E</aisle>
                </stnum>
            </seat>
            <seat>
                <pas>
                    <fname>Unoccupied</fname>
                    <lname>Unoccupied</lname>
                    <age></age>
                </pas>
                <stnum>
                    <row>4</row>
                    <aisle>F</aisle>
                </stnum>
            </seat>
        </frstcls>
 </seating>
```

And here's my XSL file:

```
<html>
    <body style="font-family:verdana;">
        <h1>United Airlines</h1>




            <table border="1">

            <xsl:for-each select="BOS">

                <tr><th>Flight No.</th><th>Origin</th><th>ETD</th><th>Destination</th><th>ETA</th></tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="num"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="orig"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="etd"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="dest"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="eta"/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr><th colspan="5">Aircraft Type</th></tr>
                <tr><td colspan="5"><xsl:value-of select="crft"/></td></tr>


                <tr>
                    <th colspan="5">Crew</th>
                </tr> 

                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">Pilot</th>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="crew/pilot/pltfname"/></td>
                <td colspan="2"><xsl:value-of select="crew/pilot/pltlname"/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">Co-pilot</th>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="crew/copilot/copltfname"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="crew/copilot/copltlname"/></td>
                </tr>




                <tr>
                    <th style="padding: 12px; font-size:1.5em;" colspan="5">Seating</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th style="padding: 5px;">Business First</th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">Seat</th><th colspan="2">Name</th><th>Adult/Child</th>
                </tr>


                <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="seating/frstcls/seat/stnum/row"/></td></tr>

                 </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: "*I am trying to create a document which displays seating information for 4 different flights*" Why don't you show us an example of XML that has at least two flights - as well as the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by this line in your stylesheet:

```
<tr><td><xsl:value-of select="seating/frstcls/seat/stnum/row"/></td></tr>
```

The XPath `seating/frstcls/seat/stnum/row` selects all the `row` elements, but in XSLT 1.0 the string value of a sequence (= what is returned by `xsl:value-of`) is just **the first item**; using XSLT 2.0 you still would not get your expected result, as you would have **all the values** inside a single cell.

What you need to do is to loop over the seating info using another `xsl:for-each`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="seating/frstcls/seat">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="stnum/row"/></td>
        <td><!-- another value --></td>
        <td><!-- ... --></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```